# Comparing a column value to list of values and if it contains the value then assigning that list value to new Column

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, feature-engineering

Column
[image]

and wanted to check with this list

```
list_CI = ['Application', 'Server & Storage', 'Active Directory',
       'Please Select Value', 'SAP', 'WPS-Core Infra Services',
       'Workplace', 'WPS-Telecoms', 'Citrix', 'Networks',
       'WPS-Connectivity Support', 'WPS-Groupware', 'WPS-Smarthands',
       'Networks & Telecomms']
```

I tried to apply lambda but fail. How can solve through regex or any other method?

Please hint and shed some light. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question: what do you mean by if it contains this value ? do you mean is the string in your list a substring of the string in the column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution, after 4-5 attempt this code solves the problem

```
 def extractServiceName(x):
    if x in  list_CI:
        return x
    else:
        return ''

Sample_data['Extracted_New_CI'] = Sample_data['CI Name'].apply(lambda x : extractServiceName(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this if this is simple and more readable:

```
Sample_data['Extracted_New_CI'] = Sample_data[Sample_data['CI Name'].isin(list_CI)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ["apply" method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) in pandas, which allows you to apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame.

So, what I did is to write a function that checks whether a given row of data frame contains one of the values in the list or not. If it contains one of the values it returns that value; otherwise, it returns None.

Then, I applied this function along axis 1 of the data frame using "apply" method.

Also, I tried to use the lower case of each word in the list and each row to prevent any consequent issues; you can remove that if the capital or lower case matter in your case.

```
def check_value(x):
    for i in list_CI:
        if i.lower() in x.lower():
           return i
    return None

df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x['CI Name']: check_value(x), axis = 1)
```

Comment: thank you for answering! However, all-code answers are discouraged; would you be able to add some corresponding text that provides explanation?

Comment: I added some explanations

Comment: Is it clear for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you for adding the explanations! I was not having this particular problem, but for those who are having this problem, they would very much appreciate the text you added.